# fat arrow function not working with jquery getJSON?

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to bind a callback to a jQuery getJSON command with the new => notation, but it's not working.

Old code (works)

```
$.getJSON("js/questions.json", function(data){
   console.log("loaded json but lost my scope...");
});
```

Fat arrow (not working)

```
$.getJSON("js/questions.json", (data) => this.test);
function test(data){
     console.log("If we get here we might still have our scope");
}
```

Comment: What is `this` a reference to in your second example?

Comment: `$.getJSON("js/questions.json", test);` or `$.getJSON("js/questions.json", (data) => test(data));`

Comment: Why do you think you need the `this.` on `this.test` in the second one?

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan, that was the answer! I simply forgot to add () to the function call.... To the others: I need 'this' to reference the object from which this code is called. It is not in the global window scope. I should have posted the complete code to clarify that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem in your arrow function is `this` just remove it and pass the data also.

```
$.getJSON("js/questions.json", (data) => test(data));
```

Or there is no need for the anonymous function just set functions reference as second argument.

```
$.getJSON("js/questions.json", test);
```

Comment: There's a big difference between those two. :-) But absolutely, the `this.` on `this.test` was the problem.

Comment: The first example is the answer, although I do need 'this'. My functions aren't called from the global window scope. I should have posted the complete code to clarify that. So the working code is (data) => this.test.bind(this,data);